# Readonly Toggle

Tags: jquery

Todos os campos de um formulário vem com `readonly`.
Utilizo a função abaixo para retirar o atributo de todos os inputs.

```
$('#form input').attr('readonly', false);
```

Porém gostaria de uma forma de fazer similar ao `toggle` do `jQuery`
Cada vez que o usuário interagir com um determinado elemento, trocar o status do `readonly`.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RESOLVIDO]

```
$("#form:input").each( function() {
   $(this).prop("readOnly",!$(this).prop("readOnly"));
});
```